# Restore dynamically granted permissions after Chrome extension updates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions, content-script

I'm trying to inject content scripts into webpages within user specified domains. I used `"http://*/"`, `"https://*/"` for `"optional_permissions"` in `manifest.json` and used `chrome.permissions.request` to dynamically gain permissions for user specified domains. But after I reload the extension, those dynamically granted permissions are gone despite my options are still there.

For example, I specified `github.com` as a target domain and after saving that Chrome will ask me to confirm this. Then when I reload the extension and check the current permissions owned by the extension, the access to `github.com` is gone. I would expect Chrome to "remember" those permissions rather than saving the options again to trigger the permission request. Or is there a way to "restore" such permissions after the extension updates?

PS. Adding listener to `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` doesn't work because it's not triggered by a "user gesture".

Comment: Probably related: [Issue 310815: Optional host permissions forgotten after browser restart](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310815). In any case I think the only thing you can do is file another bug report on https://crbug.com

Comment: You could try showing a message informing the user that Chrome forgot their permission settings, and asking them to click to regrant.

Comment: @Justin Are the granted permissions permanently gone, even after a browser restart? I wonder whether it's related to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365107 ('"Allow access to file URLs" is lost on extension update')

Comment: @wOxxOm Confirmed. I didn't notice before that restarts also lead to this problem. So I think it means that actually I cannot rely on "optional host permissions" because I cannot ask users to regrant permission on every restart...

Comment: @Rob W: Yes, they are gone even after a browser restart. So maybe I have to inject a small content scripts to every page and load actual extension logic according to my own rules...